# Laravel, jQuery - return to bracket notation after validation in Laravel (dot to bracket notation in jQuery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5.1

Using Laravel 5.1.

I have request in which I do form input validation. I call the `.ajax` method and receive the JSON output.

Something like:

```
{
    "category.subcategory_one" : ["This field must be at least 3 characters long"],
    "category.subcategory_two" : ["This field must be at least 5 characters long"],
    ...
}
```

However the inputs which are validated look like this

```
<input name="category[subcategory_one]" >
<input name="category[subcategory_two]" >
```

But now I can't add a CSS class to the inputs that weren't filled correctly because in my jQuery I have dot notation.

Is there a simple way to convert `category.subcategory_one` to `category[subcategory_one]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will need to parse those into `name` format

```
var errors ={
    "category.subcategory_one" : ["This field must be at least 3 characters long"],
    "category.subcategory_two" : ["This field must be at least 5 characters long"],
    ...
}

$.each(errors, function key, value){
  var name = key;
  if(key.indexOf('.') >-1){
     name =  key.split('.').join('[') +']';
  }
  $('[name='+name+']').append( $('<span>',{class:'error', text: value.join('<br>') })

});
```

Comment: This does it and thanks for the answer. However this won't work with multiple nestings as `category.subcategory.subsubcategory`. I don't have anything like that in my code but should I be worried about it?

Comment: if you do will need to modify

Comment: Would it be ok to do something like `key.split('.').join('][');` and then remove first `]` and last `[`? If so can you provide me with that code. I can google it if you don't know it by heart.

Comment: likely better to count parts and loop over them to create string if there are more than 2 parts in the split array

Comment: another thing would work really well is adding the same classes as the name segments ... then just add a dot prefix to create a class selector.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape special characters in the selector that contains bracket notation.

```
if (key.indexOf('.') !== -1){
    key =  key.split('.').join('\\[') +'\\]';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Will need to parse those into name format
work with multiple. Ex: key = 'category.sub1.sub2.sub3'

```
$.each( msg, function( key, value ) {

  var name = key;
  if(key.indexOf('.') >-1){
    var name =  key.split('.').join('][') +']';
    name = name.replace('][', '[');
  }

  if ($("[name='"+name+"']").is('input')) {
    $("input[name='"+name+"']").addClass('is-invalid');
  }
}
```